# RTTI Free em um objeto criado pelo Invoke

Tags: delphi, reflexão, rtti

Estou criando uma rotina para instanciar uma classe via `RTTI` e validar se essa classe implementa uma `interface`.

Tenho uma classe teste implementada da seguinte forma:

```
unit teste.classeTeste.uclasseTeste;
interface
uses
  validador;
type
  ClasseTeste = class(TInterfacedObject, IServico)
    private
    public
      function foo: string;
  end;
implementation
{ classe }
function ClasseTeste.foo: string;
begin
  Result := 'Teste foo';
end;
initialization
  ClasseTeste.ClassName;
end.
```

E tenho uma classe Validador implementada da seguinte forma:

```
unit validador;
interface    
uses
  Rtti;
type
  IServico = interface
  ['{46C26FED-AEDD-456F-B182-DEECB780D264}']
  end;
  Svc = class
    public
      function Validar(pClassName: string): Boolean;
  end;
implementation
uses
  SysUtils;
{ Svc }
function Svc.Validar(pClassName: string): Boolean;
var
  lContext: TRttiContext;
  lType: TRttiInstanceType;
  lObj: TObject;
begin
  Result := False;
  lType := lContext.FindType(pClassName) as TRttiInstanceType;
  if lType = nil then
    raise Exception.Create('Classe solicitada não encontrada no sistema ou ClassNameInválido');
  lObj := lType.GetMethod('Create').Invoke(lType.MetaclassType, []).AsObject;
  try
    if not Supports(lObj, IServico) then
      raise Exception.Create('A classe serviço não implementa a interface IServico!');
  finally
    lObj.Free;
  end;
  Result := True;
end;
end.
```

A questão é: No método Validar, na linha

```
`lObj.Free`;
```

Ele estoura

> "Invalid Pointer Operation".

Teoricamente tenho um `TObject` instanciado. Ele precisa ser liberado em algum momento. Como e quando libero ele?

Obs.: Estou usando o Delphi 2010.

Comment: Tu passou `'ClasseTeste'` pra execução da tua procedure?

Comment: Na verdade, para o RTTI funcionar tenho que passar no namespace + a classe. A chamada ficou:  if objValidador.Validar('teste.classeTeste.uclasseTeste.ClasseTeste') then
    ShowMessage('Classe Valida!');

Comment: Desculpe, mas preciso aprender a usar esse editor ainda...

Comment: Eu creio que é porque ele tá derivado de `interface`, e aí o Delphi por conta própria se livra da instância. Teste com o `ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown := True`, e não execute o `Free`. Se ao fechar a aplicação não mostrar uma mensagem com "ClasseTeste x1" então está acontecendo o que eu disse mesmo.

Comment: No Delphi 2010, o FastMM não vem embutido. Eu adicionei e rodei. Sem dar o Free ele não acusa nenhum "MemoryLeak".   Criei uma nova variavel (lob2), fiz o create e não dei o Free, e acusou o "MemoryLeak". Enfim, fiquei receoso pois lObj := lType.GetMethod('Create').Invoke(lType.MetaclassType, []).AsObject; no meu ver, me devolveria um TObject e não uma interface.

Comment: Eu realmente não sei te dar uma explicação plausível do porque pelo RTTI ele está usando gerenciamento via `interface` já que você está dizendo que quer criar um ClasseTeste e não uma IServico. Realmente, se você criar uma variável que por mais que herde uma interface, mas tu defina que a variável é ClasseTeste, não era pra ser gerenciado como interface, e aí causa uma MemoryLeak.

Comment: Ainda...no método Invoke - Invoke(lType.MetaclassType, []).AsObject - estou pedindo para ele me retornar "AsObject" :D

Answer (score 0):

o problema está na linha  `if not Supports(lObj, IServico) then`

quando a Função Supports é chamada ela libera o lObj e como você chama o free sempre

```
finally
   lObj.Free;
end;
```

ele tenta liberar novamente, ocasionando o erro, faça o teste, implemente o método

```
destructor Destroy; override;
```

na sua classe ClasseTeste e verá que ele chama duas vezes o Free.

Comment: Desculpe, mas não consegui enxergar isso. O código da funcao Supports, em SysUtils, `Result := (Instance <> nil) and (Instance.QueryInterface(IID, Intf) = 0);`

Comment: debugando aqui seu exemplo, e implementando o destroy percebi isso